I was trying to calculate standard error from log odd ratio, Is this calculation correct?
I have two datasets. The first dataset have odd ratio, 95% confidence interval, p-value, and 2x2 table. while, the second dataset only have odd ratio, 95% confidence interval, and p-value without 2x2 table. I'm trying to do a meta-analysis of these data but I need to calculate standard error of log(odd ratio) from the two dataset. So I try using a method I learned from this threat.
Data available :
Study        p-value      Odd ratio     log(odd ratio)   95% CI
1            0.009        2.560         0.408           1.260-5.200
2            0.648        1.056         0.228           0.840-1.324

Table 2x2 from the first dataset :
               Exposure (Y)       Exposure (N)
Event (Y)           34                 19
Event (N)           35                 50

With that, I calculate z for the two dataset. for p = 0.009 (two tail), this is z = 2.612. for p = 0.648 (two tail), this is z= 0,456. So SE=log(OR)/z, it yield SE = 0.156 for the first dataset and SE = 0.500 for the second dataset.
Then, with Revman 5.4.1, I got:

My question are :

Is this correct?
Somehow, the confidence interval are different before and after the meta-analysis, is this normal?


Here's what I calculated in Excel and RevMan:

Blockquote



Thank you so much. I think your calculation is correct. I would like to clarify. my calculation is simply incorrect because calculation of log(odd ratio) and the rounding of the first odd ratio dataset?

The Z's should be 2.61205 and 0.45654, respectively, for study 1 and study 2. That would give SE's of 0.35933 and 0.11935, respectively. I think that's where the error is in your calculations.
